# ObjectMapper readValue with two Children Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, objectmapper

Is there anyone who knows how to load this data from a JSON file? The Child1 and Child2 tables remain blank when trying to load the data. I would be very grateful for help or information on where I can read about this.

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext =
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    ParentRepository parentRepository = configurableApplicationContext.getBean(ParentRepository.class);

    JsonNode rootArray = mapper.readTree(new File(<SRC>));
    for(JsonNode root:rootArray)
    {
        Parent parent = mapper.treeToValue(root,Parent.class);
        parentRepository.save(parent);
    }

}
```

}

Repository:

```
   @Repository
    public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent,Long> {
    }
    @Repository
    public interface Child2Repository extends CrudRepository<Child2,Long> {
    }
    @Repository
    public interface Child1Repository extends CrudRepository<Child1,Long> {
    }
```

Childs:

```
@Entity
 @Table(name="Parent")
 public class Parent {
    
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Long Id;
    
 @OneToMany(
                mappedBy="parent",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true
        )
 private List<Child2> child2list = new ArrayList<>();
    
 @OneToMany(
                mappedBy="parent",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true
        )
 private List<Child1> child1list = new ArrayList<>();
    
 public void setchild2list(List<Child2> child2list) {
            this.child2list = child2list;
        }
    
 public void setchild1list(List<Child1> child1list) {
            this.child1list = child1list;
        }
    }


@Entity
@Table(name="Child1")
public class Child1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Long weight;
    private String weightUnit;
    private Long pieces;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;


    public Child1(Long weight, String weightUnit, Long pieces, Parent parent) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.weightUnit = weightUnit;
        this.pieces = pieces;
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name="Child2")
public class Child2 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Long weight;
    private String weightUnit;
    private Long pieces;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    public Child2(Long weight, String weightUnit, Long pieces, Parent parent) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.weightUnit = weightUnit;
        this.pieces = pieces;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "Child2": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "weight": 624,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 429
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "weight": 18,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 739
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "weight": 404,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 101
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "weight": 370,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 281
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "weight": 923,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 922
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "weight": 387,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 196
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "weight": 69,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 206
      }
    ],
    "Child1": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "weight": 743,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 383
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "weight": 352,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 34
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "weight": 788,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 771
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Child2": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "weight": 504,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 323
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "weight": 660,
        "weightUnit": "kg",
        "pieces": 181
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "weight": 264,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 757
      }
    ],
    "Child1": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "weight": 582,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 909
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "weight": 695,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 746
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "weight": 599,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 140
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "weight": 591,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 570
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "weight": 137,
        "weightUnit": "lb",
        "pieces": 712
      }
    ]
  }...
```

I've searched the forums and google for information, but haven't found many sticking points. I am new to this technology.

Comment: In the `Parent`-entity, the properties are called `child1list` and `child2list`, in the json-file, they are called `Child1` and `Child2`. This does not match. We should either rename `child1list` and `child2list` to `Child1` and `Child2` or annotate them with `@JsonProperty("Child1")` and `@JsonProperty("Child2")` respectively. This should also allow us to remove this line: `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`. Can you confirm that this fixes the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these options or both at once solved the problem. "Unrecognized field "Id" (class com.demo.model.Parent), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "Child2", "Child1"])"

Comment: Ah yeah. Try writing a setter for `id`. We should also provide setters for all attributes in `Child1` and `Child2` since jackson - by default - does not use all-args constructors. We also need to define no-args constructor for those classes in this case.